# How are the covariance and correlation of $n > 2$ random variables defined?

Tags: probability, statistics, covariance, correlation

I recently came across a theorem with the premise that "$I_1, \cdots, I_n$ are uncorrelated indicator random variables."

Nothing is said about the value of $n$, but I think it's safe to assume that, in general, it can be greater than 2.

On the other hand, I have not found any definition of "uncorrelatedness" for $n > 2$ random variables.  More specifically, I have not found any definition of either the covariance or the correlation of more than 2 random variables.

What are these definitions?

Comment: You simply take the covariances and correlation coefficients for each pair of variables. So you end up with $n(n-1)/2$ different covariances and correlation coefficients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [covariance matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariance_matrix). Essentially, you view $(I_1,\dots,I_n)$ as a random vector in $\mathbb R^n$, then the covariance matrix, $C$, is symmetric with $(i,j)^{\mathrm{th}}$ entry $C_{i,j}=\mathrm{Cov}(I_i, I_j)$.

Saying that your random variables $I_1,\dots,I_n$ are uncorrelated then amounts to $C$ being diagonal, namely $$\mathrm{Cov}(I_i, I_j)=0,\quad\forall i\neq j.$$